# How to observe changes in UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an `@ObservedObject` in my View:

```
struct HomeView: View {

    @ObservedObject var station = Station()

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.station.status)
    }
```

which updates text based on a `String` from `Station.status`:

```
class Station: ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "status") ?? "OFFLINE" {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(status, forKey: "status")
        }
    }
```

However, I need to change the value of `status` in my `AppDelegate`, because that is where I receive my [Firebase Cloud Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

  // Print full message.
  let rawType = userInfo["type"]

  // CHANGE VALUE OF status HERE
}
```

But if I change the `status` `UserDefaults` value in `AppDelegate` - it won't update in my view.

How can my `@ObservedObject`in my view be notified when `status` changes?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the 2.0 beta version of SwiftUI is used in the said example.

Comment: The code is not using observed object correctly. You should declare with `@ObservedObject var station: Station`, therefore when you create the view you will pass it the station. Assuming you set status with the same station object, the view should update correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is possible solution

```
import Combine

// define key for observing
extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var status: String {
        get { string(forKey: "status") ?? "OFFLINE" }
        set { setValue(newValue, forKey: "status") }
    }
}

class Station: ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: String = UserDefaults.standard.status {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.status = status
        }
    }

    private var cancelable: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        cancelable = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.status)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] newValue in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if newValue != self.status { // avoid cycling !!
                    self.status = newValue
                }
            })
    }
}
```

**Note: SwiftUI 2.0** allows you to use/observe `UserDefaults` in view directly via `AppStorage`, so if you need that status only in view, you can just use

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @AppStorage("status") var status: String = "OFFLINE"
    ...
```

Comment: `@AppStorage` looks exactly what I need - I'll try that out. Hopefully the view updates when I change the `status` `UserDefault` value in my `AppDelegate`. Thankyou!

Comment: Did you mean `set(newValue, forKey: "status")` instead of `setValue(newValue, forKey: "status")`?

Comment: If I read correctly, one can use UserDefaults instead of Observables, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use **environment object** instead or a combination of both of them if required. Environment objects are basically a **global state** objects. Thus if you change a **published** property of your environment object it will reflect your view. To set it up you need to pass the object to your initial view through **SceneDelegate** and you can work with the state in your **whole view hierarchy**. This is also the way to pass data across very distant sibling views (or if you have more complex scenario).

### Simple Example

In your SceneDelegate.swift:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(GlobalState())

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

The global state should conform **ObservableObject**. You should put your global variables in there as **@Published**.

```
class GlobalState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool
    
    init(isLoggedIn : Bool) {
        self.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn
    }
}
```

*Example of how you publish a variable, not relevant to the already shown example in SceneDelegate*

This is then how you can work with your global state inside your view. You need to inject it with the **@EnvironmentObject** wrapper like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var globalState: GlobalState

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Now in your case you want to also work with the state in AppDelegate. In order to do this I would suggest you safe the global state variable in your AppDelegate and access it from there in your SceneDelegate before passing to the initial view. To achieve this you should add the following in your AppDelegate:

```
var globalState : GlobalState!
    
static func shared() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

Now you can go back to your SceneDelegate and do the following instead of initialising GlobalState directly:

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(AppDelegate.shared().globalState)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However I think `@AppStorage` in SwiftUI 2.0 may be more efficient so I'll try that instead: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper

Comment: example and description is here: https://betterprogramming.pub/observe-userdefaults-using-combine-in-swift-5-4177ae62360d