# willSet not being called on SwiftUI's new @AppStorage property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am utilising SwfitUI's new `@AppStorage` property. However, the `willSet` property observer is not firing.

Here is my `UserDefaults` value `codeResult` changing from an asynchronous call:

```
class Main: ObservableObject {
    func code(data: [AnyHashable:Any?]){
        UserDefaults.standard.set("incorrect", forKey: "codeResult")
    }
}
```

And below in my View, willSet is not being called:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var main = Main()
    @ObservedObject var mainCountdown: CountDown
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @State var showCode: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("codeResult") var codeResult = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "codeResult") ?? "" {
        willSet {
            print("willSet: \(newValue)") // doesn't fire 
        }
        didSet {
            print("didSet: \(oldValue)") // doesn't fire
        }
    }
```

Any idea why it's not firing?

Answer (score 1):

The willSet/didSet are observers for property change (not publisher observers). Thus to get into willSet/didSet you have to change property `codeResult` directly.

Here is a demo that depicts differences - both buttons update Text (because `codeResult` is dynamic observable property, but only direct assign to `codeResult` activates property willSet/didSet)

Tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14.

```
struct DemoAppStorageDidSet: View {
    @AppStorage("codeResult") var codeResult: String = "Default" { // << default value
        willSet {
            print("willSet: \(newValue)")
        }
        didSet {
            print("didSet: \(oldValue)")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Code Result: \(codeResult)")
            Divider()
            Button("AppStore Update") {
                self.codeResult = "AppStore"   // << activates willSet/didSet !!
            }
            Divider()
            Button("UserDefaults Update") {
                UserDefaults.standard.set("UserDefaults", forKey: "codeResult")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: you don't need to initialise `AppStorage` with UserDefaults value, it is read by default.*

Comment: Thanks. Is there no other way to perform code in the View when `UserDefaults.standard.string("UserDefaults", forKey: "codeResult")` is changed in another file?

Comment: For any out-of-view-draw actions you can use publisher as before [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62716736/12299030)

Comment: Thanks - I also just tried `.onReceive(self.codeResult.publisher.collect())` in the View and that also works

Answer (score 0):

Adding `onReceive()` to the view seemed to successfully track changes to `codeResult` where I could execute code blocks:

```
    .onReceive(self.codeResult.publisher.collect()) {_ in
        if self.codeResult == CodeResult.incorrect.rawValue {
            print("CHANGED TO INCORRECT")
            self.showCode = false
        }
    }
```