# UserDefaults state not refresh

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui, userdefaults

I use "UserDefaults" to store the date time of the user to reload the page. However, I found that it does not refresh even if the time passed

```
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lastLaunchDate: Date = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastLaunch") as? Date ?? Date()

    func getTimeStamp() -> Date {
                    
            let now_components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: Date())
            let lastLaunch_components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: lastLaunchDate)
            
            print(now_components.minute, lastLaunch_components.minute)
            
            if now_components.minute != lastLaunch_components.minute {
                lastLaunchDate = Date()
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(lastLaunchDate, forKey: "lastLaunch")
            }
            print(now_components.minute, lastLaunch_components.minute)
        }
        return lastLaunchDate
    }
}
```

Since I am testing, I use 'minute' to ease my test. I expect that when there is change of minute, the above piece of code will update my userDefaults.

```
struct HomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(modelData.getTimeStamp())")
    }
}
```

I found that I browse into another page, go back to HomeView. The timestamp did not get update at all. I printed the lastLaunchDate, it also did not update as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62716736/12299030?

Answer (score 2):

> I found that I browse into another page, go back to HomeView. The
> timestamp did not get update at all.

If you navigate back to a parent `View`, SwiftUI does not re-render it unless something changes.
Instead... you will need to use the `.onAppear` view modifier to call your function.

Also, `Text("\(modelData.getTimeStamp())")` is not very `SwiftUI` especially in your case.
Since you have `@Published var lastLaunchDate`, use it as it's meant to be used:

```
Text("\(modelData.lastLaunchDate)")
```

Now when `lastLaunchDate` is changed, the `SwiftUI` engine will automatically update the `View`.

### Solution:

```
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lastLaunchDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastLaunch") as? Date ?? Date()
    
    func refresh() {
        let compareDate = Date()
        let refreshInterval = TimeInterval(3) //3 second interval for test purpose
        
        if compareDate.timeIntervalSince(lastLaunchDate) > refreshInterval {
            lastLaunchDate = compareDate
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(lastLaunchDate, forKey: "lastLaunch")
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(modelData.lastLaunchDate)")
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination"),
                               label: { Text("Navigate") })
            }
            .onAppear {
                modelData.refresh()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

NOTE:
`if now_components.minute != lastLaunch_components.minute` is error prone.
Example: compare last-update-time of 00:01 with current-time of 01:01.
Check will fail.